# Create div elements that automatically self-destruct

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function called `gainGold()` that `append`s a div Element to a parent like this:

```
function gainGold() {
    $('#main').append('<div class="popup popup-gold">+ 14</div>');
}
```

In the full version, the number is of course variable and there's some more to it, but i'll keep this simple. This element plays a css animation over 0.5 seconds, and i want it to be destroyed afterwards. So far, i've done that with a `setTimeout` like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.popup-gold').remove();
}, 510);
```

But this is bad practice. With this solution, i can't have multiple `popup` elements visible at once, since the jQuery selector targets all of them when removing.

Is there some way to create this div element and maintain tight control over it to just remove() it individually?

Edit: [**This is a Jsfiddle that demonstrates the solution.**](http://jsfiddle.net/x0wco7db/7/) I've ended up using Robs answer, declaring each appended element as a variable and removing it cleanly. Thanks!

Comment: can;t you have different ids? gainGold when is called?

Comment: Have you tried giving each one a specific id? Almost like a counter?

Comment: If possible , can post `css` `animation` ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save a reference to the object you are appending for removal...

```
function gainGold() {
    var popup = $('<div class="popup popup-gold">+ 14</div>');
    $('#main').append(popup);

    setTimeout(function(){
        popup.remove();
    }, 510);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's right in front of your eyes :)
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$( ".popup-gold" ).animate({

    left: "+=50",
    }, 5000, function() {
    $(this).remove();

    });
```

Comment: Thank's for the heads up, i wasn't aware of that, but unfortunately my animation is a bit too complex for `.animate()` (5 keyframes in CSS3). And wouldn't this have the same problem since you use a singular target, the class?

Comment: well it could be changed to something like $("classname[name='nameAsVar']").animate()...